# SwiftUI polymorphic behaviour not working for View

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols

```
protocol BackgroundContent: View{
  
}
struct BlueDivider: BackgroundContent {
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .frame(minHeight: 1)
            .background(.blue)
    }
}
struct RedDivider: BackgroundContent {
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .frame(minHeight: 1)
            .background(.red)
    }
}

var p: BackgroundContent = BlueDivider() 
// Use of protocol 'BackgroundContent' as a type must be written 'any BackgroundContent'

p = RedDivider()
```

This always ask me to use

```
var p: any BackgroundContent = BlueDivider()
```

Is there any way to use **generic** type which **accept any kind view**?

Actually, I want to use view as a state like `@State private var bgView: BackgroundContent = BlueDivider()` which i want to change at runtime like `bgView = RedDivider()`

I have made my custome view to place some other view at runtime by using this state.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem you can do something like this here:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isRed = false

    var body: some View {
        Devider()
            .frame(height: 1)
            .background(isRed ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complicated but i have found a solution of this problem. First thing i have done with ObservableObject. Here is my example.

```
protocol BaseBackgroundContent {
    var color: Color { get set }
}

class BlueContent: BaseBackgroundContent {
    var color: Color = .blue
}

class RedContent: BaseBackgroundContent {
    var color: Color = .red
}
```

And i created a custom view for Divider in this case.

```
struct CustomDivider: View {
    
    var backgroundContent: any BaseBackgroundContent
    
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .background(backgroundContent.color)
    }
}
```

And now i used a viewModel which can be observable, and the protocol has to be Published.

```
class ExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var backgroundContent: any BaseBackgroundContent = RedContent()
    
    func change() {
        backgroundContent = BlueContent()
    }
}
```

Final step is the view. This is a exampleView. If you click the button you will see the BlueContent which was RedContent

```
struct Example: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ExampleViewModel()
    
    init() {
       
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
           
            CustomDivider(backgroundContent: viewModel.backgroundContent)
                
            Button("Change") {
                viewModel.change()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried my answer ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Volkan Sonmez. I don't want to just change the color of **CustomeView**. 

I have a textfield widget view and want to apply different custom background which ever the user want.

The background view may be a divider, rectangle or rounded rectangle etc. I don't want the user to use fixed background style. The user can make his custom background the then set to the textfield

In textfield widget, I want to set this background at specific HStack/VStack because I'm using error view or limit view with in textfield widget. I don't want to set the background at all.

Comment: But you can use them with my solution. You can add new propertyies to your protocol. if i think you only want to change background color, then you can just set the color of divider. It is not about the color by the way. You can add new properties for your textfields. There is something you should know, you can do it like that.